# Clear div that is using display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have dynamic content that can vary greatly in width. I am trying to avoid using a min-width if at all possible. I have a jsFiddle to show you what I am dealing with. Case 1 is what I want to happen everytime regardless of the width of the content. Case 2 is what happens when the content is too short. Any way around this? Or is min-width the way to go?

```
#container {
    width:200px;
}
#div1 {
    display:inline-block;
}
#div2 {
    display:inline-block;
}
#div3 {
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vKTGy/1/

Comment: I don't get why you don't just use `display: block` on `#div3`?

Comment: Advice: do not use same `id` for different elements. Consider using classes instead.

Comment: Artyom, it's a jsfiddle.  Jared, I'm using display block so that the div can be as small as the content is. Otherwise it would fill the container width

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vKTGy/3/

Comment: Then use `float` or wrap your content in `#div3` within a `span` and style that instead.

Comment: I don't see how this would work.. JsFiddle?

Comment: @jagsrocknfl, see (updated) http://jsfiddle.net/vKTGy/9/ Of course, now you have to deal with float clearing, which is a PITA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... You could abuse `display: table-cell` for those browser versions which support it:

```
#container {
    width:200px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#div1 {
    display:table-cell;
}
#div2 {
    display:table-cell;
}
#div3 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKTGy/7/

Or manipulate floats:

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#div1 {
    float: left;
}
#div2 {
    float: left;
}
#div3 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vKTGy/8/

Comment: Jared thanks alot. You got it man. I think your comment solution is good enough until all browsers adapt to html5! "@jagsrocknfl, see (updated) jsfiddle.net/vKTGy/9 Of course, now you have to deal with float clearing, which is a PITA"

Comment: Only legacy versions (I believe IE8<) don't support `display: table-` properties. I suspect that `float`s are what you *really* wanted to begin with, and this seems to be a case (text layout) in which it was designed, not a faux table-based-layout replacement hack as many still approach `float`s (e.g., *clearfixing*).

Answer (score 0):

Must the content div be an inline-block? Changing the content div to a block level element should fix this.

```
display: block;
```

Comment: That would work but I it will max the div to the width of the container.. I'm looking for a way to keep the div as small as the dynamic content being fed into it, yet forcing it down to a newline..